# UIScrollview events will be caught by included UIButtons

Tags: objective-c, ios, events, uiscrollview, uibutton

I implemented a UIScrollview and added a lot of UIButtons inside. But now there is only a little space for scroll within the scrollview. 
If I try to scroll the scrollview on a UIButton the scrollview won't move. The cause for that is that the UIButtons catch the necessary events for the scrollview.

Could anybody help me to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set **`canCancelContentTouches`** on your `UIScrollView`. This lets the `UIScrollView` class allow touches within it's subviews.

```
[myScrollview setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think the problem here is rather that the UIButton within the scrollview cancels the event. So the scrollview won't receive the events again.